# Помогите написать select запрос на Yii и получить num_rows

Tags: php, yii

Нужно выполнить запрос к бд, а затем проверить количество строк ответа. Вот как я пытаюсь

```
              $connection = Yii::app()->db;
              $sql = "select unique_id
                         from clients
                        where unique_id = '{$params['client_id']}'";
              $qry = $connection->createCommand($sql);
              $findUserInDb = $qry->execute();
              if ($findUserInDb->rowCount < 1) {
                //пользователь не нашелся
              }
```

ошибка в строке $findUserInDb->rowCount 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: А читал в документации __что именно__ возвращает `execute()`?

Comment: `queryAll()` вместо `execute()`

Comment: @DiMithras  тоже не работало почему-то. а вот с просто query помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$sql = "select unique_id
        from clients
        where unique_id = '{$params['client_id']}'";
$qry = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$findUserInDb = $qry->queryAll();
if (empty($findUserInDb)) {
    //пользователь не нашелся
}
```

[`execute()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#execute()-detail) возвращает количество строк, затронутых запросом (количество затронутых записей), а не объект с результатом запроса, не result set.

А вот [`queryAll()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#queryAll()-detail) выдаст все строки результата, и их можно посчитать.

Впрочем, зачем считать и получать все строки, если можно чуть более оптимально проверить на наличие результата через [`query()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#query()-detail) или даже [`queryRow()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryRow-detail) / [`queryOne()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#queryOne%28%29-detail):

```
$findUserInDb = $qry->queryRow();
if ($findUserInDb === false) {
    //пользователь не нашелся
}
```

Comment: queryAll тоже не работал, пробовал его. а вот queryRow() сработал - спасибо!